# Codeblocks compile and run works but clicking on exe doesn't

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am new to C programming. I downloaded [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) to try. I had already installed the gcc compiler and so that's what codeblocks is set to use. I wrote a simple program and compile and ran it. It ran fine when I ran it from inside Code::Blocks but when I tried to double click the `.exe` it said

```
"The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your
computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."
```

Why is it that it works when I run it in Code::Blocks but not when I click on the file?

BTW, here are my `#include`s.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

Comment: Includes are immaterial at run-time.  The problem is that Code::Blocks is setting some environment information that tells the program (more accurately, the run-time support system) where to find the GCC library, but when you just click on the `.exe`, that information is not available so it fails to run.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So does this mean that gcc would need to be installed on every computer that runs this program?

Comment: You wouldn't need the full GCC installation if you're not compiling code on those other machines, but you do need the GCC run-time support library, just as you need the Microsoft run-time support library to run most programs compiled with MSVC.  Of course, the MS library is already installed because MS programs need it too.  By contrast, the GCC library isn't necessarily there because MS programs don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

I think author already solved his problem, but I just want to add my solution.
To use your executable file you need to follow these steps, to configure your project:

1. Project -> Build Options
2. Select correct target or project in left hand panel
3. Tab: Linker Settings
4. Box: Other linker settings
5. Enter follow linker options one per line:

   -static

   -static-libgcc

   -static-libstdc++

Also,it could be helpful to add (..\mingw\bin) path  to the project search directories.

Comment: this is a clean method unlike copying the libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll or any other missing dll files to the .exe Debug or release folder

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and run you're program from the terminal? If not, do so, because then you won't have the problem that you compiler won't be found.

In your home directory in the terminal call to compile:

```
gcc yourprogram.c -o yourprogram.exe

./yourprogram.exe arg1 arg2
```

Second one is to run; arg1 and arg2 would be command line arguments you pass to the program. (This works on Mac and Linux, I have 0 experience on Windowsterminal)

Anyway, if you really want to learn how to program, then you should learn how to work with the terminal; then you'll never have to worry about GUI-Problems ever again, which is what you're now doing.

Comment: The problem isn't with running the compiler, but rather with running the produced exe file. Since the `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` file exists in the Code::Blocks folder, his exe isn't loading it when double-clicked (or run from the cmd line). Jonathan's answer(comment) is the correct one.

Comment: Ok, sry, I misinterpreted the question, I thought by saying "I had already installed the gcc compiler" the compiler and so everything related is properly installed...

Comment: There's no problem, nor need to apologize. We're all here trying to help or get some when we need it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: running the exe inside CodeBlocks it was working, but running it inside `cmd` terminal gave the error.

I solved copying **MinGW** libs inside `c://windows/SysWOW64`(for 64bit windows).

I attach the zip with libs
https://3.sharebylink.com/1/?wjiteTTdXR8k or 
https://files.fm/u/b6wqqwdy

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after about 4 hours of fighting with it, I finally got it figured out.
All you have to do is click project at the top of the screen, then build options, then checkmark Static libgcc, Static libstdc++, and static linking. click ok and then rebuild your project.
Hope that helps.